# Match beginning of the line only if pattern is found anywhere after the first part of the positive lookahead

Tags: regex, vscode-extensions, oniguruma

I'm having a hard time with vscode's oniguruma regex parsing for TextMate. Apparently you can't use a newline inside a lookahead, even though oniguruma actually supports it, it's probably not enabled in vscode's version of oniguruma.

I need to match the beginning of a string ***if, and only if***, after `element` there is `desiredAttr1="desiredValue1"` or `desiredAttr2="desiredValue2"`:

```html
<element attribute="value" desiredAttr1="desiredValue1" desiredAttr2="desiredValue2">
```

So far so good, but the thing is, these attributes can be in any order, and there can be a newline in between them. Eg.:

```html
<!-- Should match -->
<element
   attribute="value"
   desiredAttr1="desiredValue1"
   desiredAttr2="desiredValue2"
>

<!-- Should match -->
<element
   attribute="value"
   desiredAttr2="desiredValue2"
>

<!-- Should match -->
<element attribute="value" desiredAttr1="desiredValue1">

<!-- Should match -->
<element desiredAttr2="desiredValue2" attribute="value">

<!-- Should NOT match -->
<element
   attribute="value"
   notDesiredAttr1="desiredValue1"
   notDesiredAttr2="desiredValue2"
>
```

This is what I got so far (and it works on rubular):

```js
/(^[\t]+)?(?=<(?i:element)\b(?!-)[\s\w\W]*(?:((desiredAttr1="desiredValue1")|(desiredAttr2="desiredAttr2"))))/
```

Note: I tried also replacing `\s` with `[:space:]` and `[^/]`

This is what I need to match:

```html
<span style="background: red;">&nbsp;</span><code>&#60;element<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;attribute="value"<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;desiredAttr1="desiredValue1"<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;desiredAttr2="desiredValue2"<br/>
&#62;</code>
```

Is there any other alternative I could use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no angle brackets in between, you could use:

```
^[\p{Zs}\t]*(?=<element\b[^<>\r]*\bdesiredAttr([12])="desiredValue\1"[^<>\r]*>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match optional spaces or tabs
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `<element\b` Match `element` followed by a word boundary
  - `[^<>\r]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `<` `>` or
    `\r`
  - `\bdesiredAttr([12])=` match `desiredAttr` and capture either 1 or 2 in **group 1**
  - `"desiredValue\1"` match `"desiredValue\1"` where `\1` is a backreference to the captured digit in group 1 (to match the same digit)
  - `[^<>\r]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `<` `>` or
    `\r`
  - `>` Match literally
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMF5Rw/1).

[image]

Comment: This would match the strings itself, I need to match the beginning of the string like I put highlighted in the code snippet...

Comment: @ghaschel It is not clear for me what you want to match, do you want `<!-- Should match -->`?

Comment: The beginning of the string itself. I think you'll understand better if you click on Run code snippet at the end of my question. There is a character marked in red.

Comment: @ghaschel Like this including newlines etc..? https://regex101.com/r/gNR6Wu/1

Comment: Or like this https://regex101.com/r/hMF5Rw/1 `^[\p{Zs}\t]*(?=<element\b[^<>\r]*\bdesiredAttr([12])="desiredValue\1"[^<>\r]*>)`

Comment: Just like that, yes. But not using lookahead, as apparently it is not supported. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @ghaschel did you uncheck the button with the 3 lines "Find in selection"

Comment: @ghaschel There is also an option with 2 capture groups, and if you are replacing for example, you can use those groups in the replacement. See https://regex101.com/r/973PFN/1 and https://imgur.com/CfgnEqb

Comment: I am using it for developing a textmate grammar. But I think I might have ran into a limitation and I'll have to try to do things in a different way. Thanks a lot for your time either way